# Sendmail does not allow some Asterisk voicemail notifications to be sent

Tags: email, sendmail, asterisk

I have a large asterisk/freepbx installation where some users are unable to leave a voicemail, and have the voicemail sent via email to the callee.  In maillog, here's what I see:

`maillog:Jan 18 15:43:33 telcosrv01 sendmail[21439]: q0ILhXBg021439: from=root, size=3425, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201201182143.q0ILhXBg021439@{pbx hostname}>, relay=root@localhost`

That notification was not sent.  A good send looks like this:

`Jan 19 08:18:19 telcosrv01 sendmail[32042]: q0JEIJFM032042: from=root, size=65018, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<Asterisk-1-256041358-9651-3969@telcosrv01.domain>, relay=root@localhost`

`Jan 19 08:18:19 telcosrv01 sendmail[32042]: q0JEIJFM032042: to="Kxxxxxx Fxxxxxx" <k.fxxxxxx@domain>, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=95018, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q0JEIJUi032045 Message accepted for delivery)`

The main differences are that `nrcpts=1` in the good log, and the msgid contains `Asterisk-1` in the good capture, while the bad log does not have this prefix.  95% of notifications work, but some users consistently cannot send out notifications.  Below is my sendmail.mc file.

```
divert(-1)dnl
dnl #
dnl # This is the sendmail macro config file for m4. If you make changes to
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, you will need to regenerate the
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file by confirming that the sendmail-cf package is
dnl # installed and then performing a
dnl #
dnl #     make -C /etc/mail
dnl #
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Do not advertize sendmail version.
dnl #
dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl
dnl #
dnl # default logging level is 9, you might want to set it higher to
dnl # debug the configuration
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Uncomment and edit the following line if your outgoing mail needs to
dnl # be sent out through an external mail server:
dnl #
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl
dnl # Added for FPBX:
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`telcosrv01.domain')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
dnl #
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following allows relaying if the user authenticates, and disallows
dnl # plaintext authentication (PLAIN/LOGIN) on non-TLS links
dnl #
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # PLAIN is the preferred plaintext authentication method and used by
dnl # Mozilla Mail and Evolution, though Outlook Express and other MUAs do
dnl # use LOGIN. Other mechanisms should be used if the connection is not
dnl # guaranteed secure.
dnl # Please remember that saslauthd needs to be running for AUTH. 
dnl #
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Rudimentary information on creating certificates for sendmail TLS:
dnl #     cd /etc/pki/tls/certs; make sendmail.pem
dnl # Complete usage:
dnl #     make -C /etc/pki/tls/certs usage
dnl #
dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl #
dnl # This allows sendmail to use a keyfile that is shared with OpenLDAP's
dnl # slapd, which requires the file to be readble by group ldap
dnl #
dnl define(`confDONT_BLAME_SENDMAIL', `groupreadablekeyfile')dnl
dnl #
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl
dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl
dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following limits the number of processes sendmail can fork to accept 
dnl # incoming messages or process its message queues to 20.) sendmail refuses 
dnl # to accept connections once it has reached its quota of child processes.
dnl #
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Limits the number of new connections per second. This caps the overhead 
dnl # incurred due to forking new sendmail processes. May be useful against 
dnl # DoS attacks or barrages of spam. (As mentioned below, a per-IP address 
dnl # limit would be useful but is not available as an option at this writing.)
dnl #
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The -t option will retry delivery if e.g. the user runs over his quota.
dnl #
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
dnl #
dnl # For using Cyrus-IMAPd as POP3/IMAP server through LMTP delivery uncomment
dnl # the following 2 definitions and activate below in the MAILER section the
dnl # cyrusv2 mailer.
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl
dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to only listen on the IPv4 loopback address
dnl # 127.0.0.1 and not on any other network devices. Remove the loopback
dnl # address restriction to accept email from the internet or intranet.
dnl #
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 587 for
dnl # mail from MUAs that authenticate. Roaming users who can't reach their
dnl # preferred sendmail daemon due to port 25 being blocked or redirected find
dnl # this useful.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 465, but
dnl # starting immediately in TLS mode upon connecting. Port 25 or 587 followed
dnl # by STARTTLS is preferred, but roaming clients using Outlook Express can't
dnl # do STARTTLS on ports other than 25. Mozilla Mail can ONLY use STARTTLS
dnl # and doesn't support the deprecated smtps; Evolution <1.1.1 uses smtps
dnl # when SSL is enabled-- STARTTLS support is available in version 1.1.1.
dnl #
dnl # For this to work your OpenSSL certificates must be configured.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen on the IPv6 loopback
dnl # device. Remove the loopback address restriction listen to the network.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl
dnl #
dnl # enable both ipv6 and ipv4 in sendmail:
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')
dnl #
dnl # We strongly recommend not accepting unresolvable domains if you want to
dnl # protect yourself from spam. However, the laptop and users on computers
dnl # that do not have 24x7 DNS do need this.
dnl #
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email.
dnl # 
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following example makes mail from this host and any additional
dnl # specified domains appear to be sent from mydomain.com
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`domain')dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just the headers, but the envelope as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just @mydomainalias.com, but @*.mydomainalias.com as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you **have** to intercept some way full SMTP-session in order to see problems. Maybe increasing loglevel severity *may help*, or - define (temporary) for asterisk-generated mails **deliverable return-path** and inspect bounces

Comment: How would I enable the return-path for asterisk only?  and it appears that the bad emails do not come from asterisk, as they are missing the asterisk-1; will that be an issue?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: well, I don't know nothing about *how* these "the voicemail sent via email to the callee" - but, somehow-somewhere they are generated, if your sendmail accept incoming mails? For me 0 recipients is more issue than Message-id, which must be OK for your config, AFAICS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a script that was modifiying the stream, to both convert the .wav of the voicemail to mp3, and change the reply-to address; the piece that modified the reply-to address was pulling the wrong information occasionally.  Changing that should fix it.  Below is the part of the script that was wrong:

```
CID=`grep 'X-Asterisk-CallerID:' stream.part | cut -d " " -f 2`

if [ ${#CID} = 4 ]; then
        mv stream.part stream.part.org
        FROMADD=`grep $CID /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf | grep @ | cut -d "," -f 3`
        FROMNAME=`grep $CID /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf | grep @ | cut -d "," -f 2`
        FROMSTR="Reply-To: \"$FROMNAME\" <$FROMADD>"
        sed "/From: /i $FROMSTR" stream.part.org >> stream.part
fi
```

if any of the users in /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf would have had an extension within or as their voicemail password, the script would fail.  I modified it as follows to get past that.  I think there is a better way to get the from name/address, so if you have any suggestions, let me know.

```
CID=`grep 'X-Asterisk-CallerID:' stream.part | cut -d " " -f 2`

if [ ${#CID} = 4 ]; then
        mv stream.part stream.part.org
        FROMADD=`grep "$CID =" /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf | grep @ | cut -d "," -f 3`
        FROMNAME=`grep "$CID =" /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf | grep @ | cut -d "," -f 2`
        FROMSTR="Reply-To: \"$FROMNAME\" <$FROMADD>"
        sed "/From: /i $FROMSTR" stream.part.org >> stream.part
fi
```

Thanks!